# How do I split alternating lines of a text file into two arrays?

Tags: delphi

How would I read data from a text file into two arrays? One being string and the other integer?

The text file has a layout like this:

```
 Hello
 1
 Test
 2
 Bye
 3
```

Each number corresponds to the text above it. Can anyone perhaps help me? Would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Which part of the task is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 6):

```
var
  Items: TStringList;
  Strings: array of string;
  Integers: array of Integer;
  i, Count: Integer;
begin
  Items := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Items.LoadFromFile('c:\YourFileName.txt');
    // Production code should check that Items.Count is even at this point.

    // Actual arrays here. Set their size once, because we know already.
    // growing your arrays inside the iteration will cause many reallocations
    // and memory fragmentation.
    Count := Items.Count div 2;
    SetLength(Strings, Count);
    SetLength(Integers, Count);

    for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
    begin
      Strings[i] := Items[i*2];
      Integers[i] := StrToInt(Items[i*2+1]);
    end;
  finally
    Items.Free;
  end;
end
```

Comment: You could use `i shl 1` instead of `i*2`. It will theoretically be faster, but it's actually useless between all the overhead of file io and array allocation.. Makes you look cool, though. ;)

Comment: Actually using `shl` to multiply makes you look foolish in my view!

Comment: I added Assert, on advice by David Heffernan, but I'm not so sure about it. Assertions are for debugging purposes and shouldn't be in your production code. And they shouldn't be used for checking user input, which I consider an input file to be as well.

Comment: And thanks for correcting my code. Even indeed doesn't exist. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol: the optimizer will turn any `x * 2` into an `x shl 1`, if it can.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis. Indeed it does. Didn't even think of that. :)

Comment: @GolezTroi: Assertions can even be useful in production code.  If something goes wrong, they give you the exact line of code that failed!

Comment: @Rudy Will it? In normal code, i is an `integer` so i*2 is not the same as `i shl 1` for an integer so the optimizer won't do this - it is the case for a cardinal. In the special case of a loop and an array index starting at 0, the compiler is clever enough to guess that it will be a positive number, and will handle it as a cardinal... and by the way, array index optimization is not of a `shl 1` but indeed of a `add reg,reg` (*2) + `mov eax,[reg+reg*4]`. So for this code, there is no need to use `i shl 1`.

Comment: @Arnaud: yes, if it can. FWIW, `add reg,reg; lea eax,[reg+reg*4]` multiplies `reg` by 10 (if you use `lea`).

Comment: @Rudy It was indeed `add reg2,reg2; mov eax,[reg1+reg2*4]` to get a *8

Comment: @Arnaud: but that does not give a multiplication by 8! The `[reg+n*reg]` trick only works with `lea`, not with `mov`. `Mov` would actually try to fetch something from the given (probably invalid) address.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler. Assertions can certainly be useful in production code, but they still serve a debugging purpose. An assertion is typically used to tell you, the developer, that something in your code is wrong, because input is not thoroughly checked. In this case, the input is user input. If it is wrong, a message should be displayed to the user to tell him that the file is wrong. These kind of messages should not be triggered by Assert. You should raise another exception instead (because all Assert does, is raise an EAssertion or so).

Answer (score 2):

I would read the file into a string list and then process it item by item. The even ones are put into the list of strings, and the odd ones go into the numbers.

```
var
  file, strings, numbers: TStringList;
...
//create the lists
file.LoadFromFile(filename);
Assert(file.Count mod 2=0);
for i := 0 to file.Count-1 do
  if i mod 2=0 then 
    strings.Add(file[i])
  else
    numbers.Add(file[i]);
```

I'd probably use some helper functions called `odd` and `even` in my own code.

If you wanted the numbers in a list of integers, rather than a string list, then you would use `TList<Integer>` and add `StrToInt(file[i])` on the odd iterations.

I've used lists rather than dynamic arrays for the ease of writing this code, but GolezTrol shows you how to do it with dynamic arrays if that's what you prefer.

That said, since your state that the number is associated with the string, you may actually be better off with something like this:

```
type
  TNameAndID = record
    Name: string;
    ID: Integer;
  end;

var
  List: TList<TNameAndID>;
  Item: TNameAndID;
...
  List := TList<TNameAndID>.Create;
  file.LoadFromFile(filename);
  Assert(file.Count mod 2=0);
  for i := 0 to file.Count-1 do begin
    if i mod 2=0 then begin
      Item.Name := file[i];
    end else begin
      Item.ID := StrToInt(file[i]);
      List.Add(Item);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The advantage of this approach is that you now have assurance that the association between name and ID will be maintained. Should you ever wish to sort, insert or remove items then you will find the above structure much more convenient than two parallel arrays.

Comment: Should have known you'd beat me to it again. With Delphi being in the title and all..

Comment: @GolezTrol Well, youre answer has cleaner than mine I'd say. Put an assertion of even count and I'll upvote it!

Comment: You can set Capacity on Lists and Stringlists too. It will make them allocate a large enough buffer already.

Comment: @Golez Well, I was more concerned with the principles of picking off alternate items than worrying about memory/performance issues which are surely irrelevant to the poster. The assertion is for correctness.

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question, since it specifically asks about putting them in arrays and not stringlists. BTW, Delphi has had `Odd()` since D1, which makes `not `Odd()` the equivalent of `Even()`. :)

Comment: @Ken I never understood why `Even` was neglected. Writing `not Odd` instead of `Even` is less than ideal.

Comment: Done. But I must admit I'm not sure about yours. TStringList may be my favorite Delphi class, but the OP asked for arrays... :-/

Comment: @David, you're quick. <g> I didn't even get my edit finished before you answered. Notice I didn't down-vote, because the answer is good; it just doesn't quite answer the question asked.

Comment: @Golez delphi lists are actually arrays. Arrays have O(1) random access.  Lists are linked lists in my book.

Comment: @David. I know. Created a TIntegerList once, that was based on the source of TStringList. :)

Comment: @David: Only one of `Odd()` and `Even()` is needed, but IIRC, original Pascal had `Odd()` **and** `Even()`.

Comment: @David Oh come on, I know perfectly well that not odd = even, but who the heck wants to write not odd when they mean even. Do you describe the number 42 as being "not odd"?